# extract sub string from string within box bracket

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have following string

```
 string _sql = "SELECT   [Date] ,[Product Name] ,Sum([Revenue]) as [Revenue]  FROM [tblC6FD_Data_16_BisLanguage17112011] Group By  [Date] ,[Product Name] ";
```

I want to extract all substring inside box bracket

**i want output like this**

[Date]

[Product Name]

[Revenue]

[Date]

[Product Name]

I have tried some thing like, but completely lost

```
  var str = _sql.Split(new[] { ',' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(col => new { 
        col,token = col.TrimStart().Split().First()}).Where(x => x.token.Contains('[')).Select(x => x.token);
```

Comment: You should use Regular Expression for this.

Comment: @Heslacher can you give any sample, i tried some combination but not ale to achieve the result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a draft of the solution you are looking for, using Regular Expressions:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[[\w ]+\]");    
string[] inBrackets = regex.Matches(_sql)
                           .Cast<Match>()
                           .Select(m=>m.Value)
                           .ToArray();
```

However, keep in mind this will find all phrases in brackets, including the table name. This also means Revenue will come twice. But this should get you started.

Comment: Ye i know that, but that wont bother me at all